Discord.js DiscordAPIError[10062]: Unknown interaction error
I am trying to code a Discord bot using discord.js and I am getting random unknown interaction errors when trying to use buttons on an embed.
I believe this may be happening because the interaction takes too long to respond. It occurs when I try to click a button on the embed or use the select menu. However, I am not sure how to fix this. I have called interaction.deferReply() at the start of the interaction and am updating the message with interaction.update().
This is the error that I am getting:
/workspaces/miru/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:722
      throw new DiscordAPIError(data, "code" in data ? data.code : data.error, status, method, url, requestData);
            ^

DiscordAPIError[10062]: Unknown interaction
    at handleErrors (/workspaces/miru/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:722:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async BurstHandler.runRequest (/workspaces/miru/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:826:23)
    at async _REST.request (/workspaces/miru/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:1266:22)
    at async StringSelectMenuInteraction.update (/workspaces/miru/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/interfaces/InteractionResponses.js:233:5)
    at async InteractionCollector.<anonymous> (/workspaces/miru/commands/lists/list.js:156:9) {
  requestBody: {
    files: [],
    json: {
      type: 7,
      data: {
        content: undefined,
        tts: false,
        nonce: undefined,
        embeds: [
          {
            title: '5-toubun no Hanayome Movie',
            url: 'https://myanimelist.net/anime/48548',
            author: [Object],
            thumbnail: [Object],
            color: 16759283,
            fields: [Array],
            footer: [Object],
            timestamp: '2024-04-12T15:10:25.952Z'
          }
        ],
        components: undefined,
        username: undefined,
        avatar_url: undefined,
        allowed_mentions: undefined,
        flags: undefined,
        message_reference: undefined,
        attachments: undefined,
        sticker_ids: undefined,
        thread_name: undefined
      }
    }
  },
  rawError: { message: 'Unknown interaction', code: 10062 },
  code: 10062,
  status: 404,
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/interactions/1228361679293644890/aW50ZXJhY3Rpb246MTIyODM2MTY3OTI5MzY0NDg5MDpkQWhGNzNmcmEwZmZYZ2FvY1FobGxZbnJwYklKWEtYdVRnbzkzb3hlcmZaYWlxZVFLNzQzcUtmSGY1WVo1b1diRHIwZUVDMEhjYzJGR2ZZbFpVRmdDOTlTZm02cmdacTFuM21JQ1lFRWV3SjFDdmNDS0hEdjl3dXNIeGdqYVY5YQ/callback'
}

Here is the collector for the select menu and buttons:
const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({ time: 900000 });

    collector.on('collect', async i => {
      if (i.customId === 'select_anime') {
        currentIndex = parseInt(i.values[0]);
        await i.update({ embeds: [embeds[currentIndex]] });
      } else if (['previous', 'next'].includes(i.customId)) {
        await i.update({ embeds: [embeds[currentIndex]] });
      } else if (['prev_menu', 'next_menu'].includes(i.customId)) {
        if (i.customId === 'prev_menu' && currentMenuIndex > 0) {
          currentMenuIndex--;
        } else if (i.customId === 'next_menu' && currentMenuIndex < chunkedAnimeList.length - 1) {
          currentMenuIndex++;
        }
        rowSelectMenu.setComponents(createSelectMenu(chunkedAnimeList[currentMenuIndex], currentMenuIndex));
        menuNavigationButtons.setComponents(createMenuNavigationButtons().components);
        await i.update({ components: [rowSelectMenu, menuNavigationButtons] });
      }
    });

Here I am calling interaction.deferReply():
async execute(interaction) {
    await interaction.deferReply();

The first embed is sent when the command is sent. The rest are edited in after the user uses the select menu:
// Send the initial message
    await interaction.editReply({
      embeds: [embeds[currentIndex]],
      components: [rowSelectMenu, menuNavigationButtons]
    });

I have tried to search for a solution but I cannot find anything. I have also tried changing i.update() to using i.editReply() however, that did not work and returned with another error. Any help would be appriciated, thanks!

interaction.deferUpdate() then interaction.update()

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Where would I put deferUpdate()?
